# How to add a number to a value in all keys in a text file?

Tags: python

I need a code that adds (+1) to a value in all keys in a text file.

example:

```
Eggs, 2, bacon, 3, sausage, 5, ,
Eggs, 5, bacon, 7, sausage, 7, ,
Eggs, 1, bacon, 2, sausage, 5, ,
```

So, if i wanted to add 1 to value[5]. What code would i need for this?
end result:

```
Eggs, 2, bacon, 3, sausage, 6, ,
Eggs, 5, bacon, 7, sausage, 8, ,
Eggs, 1, bacon, 2, sausage, 6, ,
```

A full code answer would be great.

```
def add_sausage():

    L = open("list.txt","r")
    data = L.read()
    L.close()

    datalines = data.split("\n")

    null = " "

    L = open("list.txt","w")
    for line in datalines:
            s = line.strip()
            string = s.split(",")
            if null == string[6]:
                    option = raw_input("Do you want to add a sausage? y/n")
                    if option == "y":
                            string[5] = str(int(string[5]) + 1)
                    elif option == "n":
                            break
                    newline = ",".join(strings)
                    L.write(newline + "\n")
            else:
                    L.write(line + "\n")

    L.close()
```

This is my code so far. I know it doesn't work. I have tried everything for 3 weeks. I cant get anything to work because i am new to coding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please read the [tour] some time. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. (from [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask))

Comment: Have you tried to write any code? What worked and what did not?

Comment: You have a typo: `join(strings)` should be `join(string)`.

Comment: `break` ends the loop. So when the user says no, it doesn't write that line or any of the remaining lines back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating what WreckeR and Barmar correctly pointed out plus correcting for last newline written out which caused problems if the file was reprocessed, you get:

```
def add_sausage():

    L = open("list.txt","r")
    data = L.read()
    L.close()

    datalines = data.split("\n")

    L = open("list.txt","w")
    for line in datalines:
            s = line.strip()
            string = s.split(",")
            if len(string) > 1:
                    # replicate the question and if-elif for other options
                    option = input("Do you want to add a sausage? y/n\n")
                    if option == "y":
                            string[5] = str(int(string[5]) + 1)
                    elif option == "n":
                            pass
                    newline = ",".join(string)
                    L.write(newline + "\n")
    L.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_sausage()
```

Comment: This needlessly reads the entire file into memory.  Try `fileinput.input(inplace=True)` to process a line at a time and writing back over the original file.

Comment: I have inserted the code into my code and this error comes up: option = input("Do you want to add a sausage? y/n\n")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Comment: I have changed the option = input("Do you want to add a sausage? y/n\n") code to option = input("Do you want to add a round? 1 = yes and 2 = no \n"). But now this is a never ending cycle and does nothing. it recognises the numbers 1 and 2 but does nothing.

Comment: Hi tripleee, Dave, I tried using fileinput.input, with inplace=True but ran into the problem that since the function redirects stdout back to the file, it effectively writes the question in input("Do you want to add a sausage? y/n\n") to the file then stops.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as an example and adapte it to your code (**In case you want to add plus one to all numbers which value is 5**):

```
def calculate_line(line, number):
    for index, item in enumerate(line):
        if (item.strip().isdigit() and int(item.strip()) == number):
            line[index] = " "+str(int(item.strip())+1)
    return line

if __name__ == "__main__":
    line = "Eggs, 2, bacon, 5, sausage, 5, ,"
    print (line)
    print(','.join(calculate_line(line.split(","),5)))
```

Input:

```
line = "Eggs, 2, bacon, 5, sausage, 5, ,"
```

will be transformed to:

```
"Eggs, 2, bacon, 6, sausage, 6, ,"
```

Output:

```
Eggs, 2, bacon, 5, sausage, 5, ,
Eggs, 2, bacon, 6, sausage, 6, ,
```

Or even easier (**In case you want to add plus one just to the third column numbers**):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    line = "Eggs, 2, bacon, 5, sausage, 5, ,"
    print (line)
    line_data = line.split(",")
    line_data[5] = " "+str(int(line_data[5].strip())+1)
    print (','.join(line_data))
```

Output:

```
Eggs, 2, bacon, 5, sausage, 5, ,
Eggs, 2, bacon, 5, sausage, 6, ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote my previous answer so:
1. The file is rewritten in place.
2. Each menu item in each order (file line) is processed.
3. Simplifies the input file.

```
def add_sausage():
    dataline_location = 0

    with open("list.txt","r+") as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            # Need to strip end of line character and split by comma
            string = line.rstrip().split(',')
            # to correct for last newline char written out if the file is reprocessed
            if len(string) > 1:
                # for each order, i.e. line in file ask about each menu item
                for j in range(0,len(string),2):
                    option = input("For order {0} do you want to add a {1}? y/n\n".format(i+1, string[j]))
                    if option == "y":
                            string[j+1] = str(int(string[j+1]) + 1)
                    elif option == "n":
                            pass
                newline = ",".join(string)
                f.seek(dataline_location)
                f.write(newline + "\n")
                # flush write buffer straight away
                f.flush()
                # keep track of the location of the line in file
                dataline_location += len(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_sausage()
```

New input file looks like:

```
Eggs,2,bacon,3,sausage,1
Eggs,5,bacon,7,sausage,1
Eggs,1,bacon,2,sausage,1
```